# Who is a side note?

Tags: meaning, expressions, slang

> The side note typically is only friends with one girl in the group leaving every guy and maybe even a few of the girls wondering where the hell she came from. [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Side+note)

I can't seem to find any other [reliable] sources which would agree with the definition above, which makes me doubt the credibility of the note. Furthermore, downvotes to the post were almost as much as the upvotes. So this leaves me with the following questions:

- Can "side note" actually be a person?
- Is the definition above correct?
- How common is this slang use of the word?
- If the answer to the questions above is positive, can a side note be a guy or is it only about females?

Please cite proof of the use of such expression (if any).

Comment: I can't prove a negative, but I have never heard that expression, and it sounds very strange to me.  The common usage of _side note_ is more or less positive.

Comment: Urban Dictionary probably has no strict policy of checking whether some or other expression is current and entrenched. Users add new senses, some turn out to be witty, and these probably get upvoted despite not being widespread meanings.

Comment: I notice that on Urban Dictionary, the definition has 7 upvotes and 8 downvotes.  Not only do people not agree with the definition, very few people are even looking it up.  There may be people who use it, but not many.

Comment: @CopperKettle - that is correct - anyone can add a word to Urban Dictionary and define it any way they wish.  Community voting is the only filter for whether terms are real or not.

Comment: @downvoter if you downvote without telling why, you are not letting me realize where I was wrong. Why is it so hard to leave a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't prove a negative, but I have never heard that expression, and it sounds very strange to me. The common usage of side note is more or less positive.

I notice that on Urban Dictionary, the definition has 7 upvotes and 8 downvotes. Not only do people not agree with the definition, very few people are even looking it up. There may be people who use it, but not many. The thing about Urban Dictionary is that anyone can add or define a word any way they wish. Community voting is the only filter for whether terms are real or not.
As for a replacement?

*Third Wheel* is similar.  It usually refers to a person who hangs out with a couple, though (See this great definition at my favorite source, [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Third%20Wheel) (note the upvote count, though)

Other possibilities:

*Groupie*  This person follows the social group around with adulation, and may not actually know any of them well, but is star-struck by their scene.  The larger group pays the groupie minimal attention.

*Tag-along* Someone who knows the people in the group, isn't particularly close with any of them, but shows up anyway.  *Why did you tell that tag-along, Ben, we're going to the movies?  He is so annoying.*